# Power BI REST API: The remote server returned an error

Tags: rest, azure, powerbi

I recently started exploring the Power BI REST API, but today I encountered something weird.

Yesterday I downloaded the Power BI getting-started-for-dotnet project from Github. (https://github.com/PowerBI/getting-started-for-dotnet).
For this project to run, I had to do a few things on my Azure account which I did successfully. I ran the application yesterday and everything was fine.

Today however I receive an error when I try to add rows to the dataset. It gives me following error: "The remote server returned an error: (404) Not found."

I redownloaded the project, but it still gives me the same error.

Anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to set some breakpoints in the sample code and see if the dataset is actually created. If the dataset is created, and is found by the call that lists all datasets, check for the id, as there can be multiple datasets with the same name, id is unique. Finally, make sure that id is used by the POST to push rows into the dataset.

Hope this helps.